# Error of callback is not a function at Timeout._onTimeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, node-async

CODE: Named functions to recuse:

```
console.log('before');

getUser(1, getRepositories);
    // console.log('User',user);

function getRepositories(user) {
    //  console.log(user);
    getRepositories(user.gitHubUsername, getCommits);
}

function getCommits(repos) {
    getCommits(repo, displayCommits);
}

function displayCommits(commits) {
    console.log(commits);
}

console.log('after');

function getUser(id, callback) {
   setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('reading a user from databse...');
    callback({ id: id, gitHubUsername: 'mosh'});
}, 2000);
}

function getRepositories(username, callback) {
    setTimeout(() => { 
    console.log('calling GitHub API...');
    callback(['repo1', 'repo2', 'repo3']);
},2000);
}

function getCommits(repo, callback) {
    setTimeout(() => { 
    console.log('calling GitHub API...');
    callback(['commit']);
},2000);
}
```

OUTPUT:
before
after
reading a user from databse...
calling GitHub API...
C:\Users\jaini\node\async-demo\index.js:31
callback(['repo1', 'repo2', 'repo3']);
^

```
TypeError: callback is not a function
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\jaini\node\async-demo\index.js:31:5)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as you don't want your kids/pets/whatever have the same name, you should not have `function`s with the same name in the same scope. That poor JS engine could not decide which `getRepositories` or `getCommits` function you wanted to run. Try to rename these and you're good to go:

```js
console.log('before');

getUser(1, getRepositoriesByUser);

function getRepositoriesByUser(user) {
  getRepositories(user.gitHubUsername, getCommitsByRepo);
}

function getCommitsByRepo(repo) {
  getCommits(repo, displayCommits);
}

function displayCommits(commits) {
  console.log(commits);
}

console.log('after');

function getUser(id, callback) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('reading a user from database...');
    callback({ id, gitHubUsername: 'mosh' });
  }, 2000);
}

function getRepositories(username, callback) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('calling GitHub API to get repos...');
    callback(['repo 1', 'repo 2', 'repo 3']);
  }, 2000);
}

function getCommits(repo, callback) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('calling GitHub API to get commits...');
    callback(['commit A', 'commit B']);
  }, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In index.js, line 31,callback needs to be called as a function (you see that it's not in orange colour as it has not been declared)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question and should be a comment only. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).